# Sending data array to another function inside the controller

Tags: php, arrays, function, codeigniter, csv

I'm importing csv files into database using two user-defined functions.

I came up on this idea after learning about "**clean codes**", in order for my teammates to read my codes properly. Apparently I have a bad way of coding and it became a habit.

I created two user-defined function. 
1) function `csv_process($toWrite)`  & 
2) function `action()`

The first function is to process the csv file(validating the file) and the second function is to insert the data extracted from the csv file into the database.

There is an array in the first function called `$toWrite[]` where the data from the csv file is extracted, I'm trying to send this array to the second function so it could be inserted into the database.

However, I'm having difficulties in doing so. I am new to PHP also to Codeigniter so I have little knowledge on how functions work. I hope someone could help me solve this problem, I'm not sure if this is a big problem or little since I'm new.

Here is my controller along with the two functions:

Controller function `csv_process($toWrite)`

```
   $filename        = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $temp           = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $filesize       = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
    $allowed_ext    = array("csv");     
    $extension      = end($temp);

    if (!in_array($extension, $allowed_ext)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "Sorry, CSV file only.");          
    }else{
        if ($filesize < 0) {
        }else{
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            $toWrite = array();
            $error = false;
            $col_size = 2;
            $skip = 0;              
            while ($data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ","))
            {
                $skip++;
                if ($skip == 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                $numofcol = count($data);
                if ($numofcol != $col_size ) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "Column count exceeded or missing.");
                }else{
                    $name1      = $data[0];
                    $name       = str_replace("'", "''", $name1);
                    $email1     = $data[1];
                    $email      = str_replace("'", "''", $email1);
                    $toWrite[]  = array($name, $email);                     
                }                       
            }#end while
            fclose($file);  
        }
    }
```

Controller `action()`

```
   $this->csv_process();
    foreach ($toWrite as $arr) {
        list($name, $email) = $arr;
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM import WHERE name ='$name'  AND email = '$email'");
        if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
        }else{
            if ($name == "" OR $email == "") {
            }else{
                if ((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) == FALSE ) {
                }else{
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO import(name, email, created_date) VALUES('".$name."', '".$email."', '".date("Y-m-d h-i-s")."')");
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'SUCCESS YEAY');
                }
            }
        }
        $query->free_result();
    }
    redirect('clean_csv/index');
```

Comment: If your function that read the CSV file just returned the array, this could then be passed onto the next stage of the code.

Comment: As a matter of style - try changing your condition so that you can remove all of those empty code blocks - `if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {` to `if ($query->num_rows() == 0 ) {` for example.

Comment: after returning the array, put the function result in your variable `$toWrite` so that you can use it in your loop

Comment: tried returning it but when I used var_dump() is show null value :( @miggy

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For insert exported data to database is best that you create a library method of model method for store data in database.

Codeigniter controller methods is action that user can be call a route (controller/action/...) so i think you must create a protected function in controller for action method or use model/library method that second approach is better.

Create method in model/library just return inserted data or true/false and your controller must decide about redirect or other actions.

Comment: We're not using model here even thou it's CI, though I'll reconsider your option.

Comment: You can use fat controller with protected action() method, or create a new ClassA and create store function into that and move your codes in this method.